# 403 response on S3 Delete Object RestAPI unless Principal is "*"

Tags: amazon-s3, elixir, amazon-iam

I am trying to delete an object using the [s3 Rest API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObject.html#API_DeleteObject_RequestSyntax) from my Elixir + Phoenix project. I can't seem to figure out what to set my s3 policy at such that it allows deleting objects. Currently, I **can** delete objects using the CLI - so something is perhaps wrong from my request origin.

My bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<MY_BUCKET>/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:user/<IAM_USERNAME>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET_NAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Elixir code reaches to s3 like so:

```
    x = HTTPoison.delete!(bucket_url, [{"x-amz-expected-bucket-owner", "<ACCOUNT_ID>"}])
    IO.inspect(x, label: ">>>>")
```

Where the inspect call returns a 403.

If I set my second statement in my bucket policy to have a principal of `*` I am able to delete objects without making any changes to my HTTP call in the elixir code. That means that something is not aligning between what I should be setting my principal to, or perhaps what the `x-amz-expected-bucket-owner` is supposed to be.

Also, my IAM user has the `AmazonS3FullAccess` permission.

Comment: It seems to me that your Elixir app is not using the IAM user/role that has `AmazonS3FullAccess` attached.

Comment: @jellycsc Thanks for the reply. The api endpoint for DeleteObject doesn't seem to receive any credentials in the headers though (apart from the aforementioned x-amz-expected-bucket-owner - which only uses the account ID)?  Could I be missing some kind of assume passing of credentials in a header that isn't mentioned in the docs?

Comment: A follow up - your comment made me realize that there is separate documentation [1] on how to sign / authenticate rest API requests. I imagine that will fix things, and I'll report back if / when it works.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had neglected to authenticate the results. Rolling your own signature signing is a bit annoying, so I ended up just switching to use [ExAws](https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws), which works great; it handles building the proper signature and makes the correct REST API calls with all the expected authentication parameters.